# Remove Number and String Pairing in List

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, python-re

I have a list of strings in Python which contain a number of cities/locations. A sampling of this list is as follows:

```
First City 0.7 WSW
Second City 1.4 SSW
3 NW Third City
0.9 N Fourth City
4 ESE Fifth City
```

My goal is to remove any numbers and the corresponding cardinal directions from the city list, such that the list looks like this:

```
First City
Second City
Third City
Fourth City
Fifth City
```

I have the following written:

```
list = ['First City 0.7 WSW', 'Second City 1.4 SSW', '3 NW Third City', '0.9 N Fourth City','4 ESE Fifth City']
pattern = r'[0.-9.]'
modify = [(re.sub(pattern, '', x)) for x in list]
```

This properly removes the numbers and corresponding decimals for a string in any given index within the list above, however I'm unsure how to handle the removal either leading or trailing each city.

How would I approach removing these cardinal direction strings?

Comment: It might be a bit tricky. Since the directions are [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction#/media/File:Brosen_windrose.svg) I think would hardcode them in the regex, and hope that there are no actual cities whose official initials is one of them

Comment: Perhaps a broad match, but for the example data `[^\S\r\n]*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? [A-Z]+\b[^\S\r\n]*` https://regex101.com/r/RIbnSR/1

Comment: @DeepSpace I was debating heading in this direction too, and I like what you propose. To your point, this list occasionally could have a scenario where the single letter cardinal directions match a city (take Worcester, MA for example).

Comment: @Thefourthbird This regex string takes care of this problem flawlessly from the tests I've run this through, I will use this as the accepted answer. Appreciate the prompt answer AND a new site I did not know existed to test these problems in!

Comment: @Thefourthbird This will remove ANY three letters that happen to be after a number

Comment: @DeepSpace That is correct, that is why I mentioned it is a broad match. You might add the allowed characters to a character class `[NESW]+` to make the range it a bit smaller, or list all the options in a capture group`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be matching the number with an optional decimal followed by 1-3 times the allowed uppercase characters.

The match the leading and trailing spaces, you could use `\s` but that could also match a newline. To match the whitespace chars without a newline, you can use `[^\S\r\n]`

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
[^\S\r\n]*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? [NESW]{1,3}\b[^\S\r\n]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0YC1W6/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Bv2Qs0)

```
    import re

strings = ["First City 0.7 WSW","Second City 1.4 SSW","3 NW Third City","0.9 N Fourth City","4 ESE Fifth City"]

for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(r"[^\S\r\n]*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? [NESW]{1,3}\b[^\S\r\n]*", "", s))
```

Output

```
First City
Second City
Third City
Fourth City
Fifth City
```

A bit more specific could be matching all the possibilities

```
[^\S\r\n]*\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? (?:N(?:N?[EW])?|E(?:[NS]E)?|SS?[EW]?|W(?:[SN]W)?)\b[^\S\r\n]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOI5rr/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could explicit cardinal directions in you regex and try to match them:

```py
cardinal_directions = sorted(
    ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', 'ENE', 'E', 'ESE', 'SE', 'SSE', 'S', 'SSW', 'SW', 'WSW', 'W', 'NWN', 'NW', 'NNW'],
    key=lambda x: len(x),
    reverse=True,
)  # sort by length, try to match the longest first

pattern = r'\s*(\d*.\d+|\d+)\s*({})\s*'.format('|'.join(cardinal_directions))
```

`pattern` is `\s*(\d*.\d+|\d+)\s*(NNE|ENE|ESE|SSE|SSW|WSW|NWN|NNW|NE|SE|SW|NW|N|E|S|W)\s*`

Here the result:

```sh
['First City', 'Second City', 'Third City', 'Fourth City', 'Fifth City']
```